# How to use stochastic variable without linking to data in PyMC?

Tags: pymc

When creating some observed data, I want to use a stochastic parameter but I do not want the stochastic parameter to be affected by this data - I don't want its likelihood to be affected by this data set. Is there a way to do that (I apologise if I have made any errors of terminology!)

To be more concrete I am trying to do something like the following:

```
nu = mc.Gamma('nu', 3, 2)
# want to have nu fit to this data set
fit_obs = mc.NoncentralT('fit', fitmean, fitprec, nu, value=fit_data, observed=True)
# want to use nu in this model but do not want this data to 
# effect the likelihood of nu
target_obs = mc.NoncentralT('target', targetmean, targetprec, nu, value=target_data, observed=True)
```

I understand in the above as it is the conditional likelihood of nu will be affected by both data sets (so it will be fit to both of them).

EDIT:
I have tried the following:

```
@mc.deterministic
def fixed_nu(nu=nu):
    return nu
```

but as shown in Cam's answer this doesn't work.

Comment: Your deterministic function won't change anything. I'll demonstrate why in my (edited) answer.

Comment: I think some more information is necessary. Why are you only fitting on part of the data?

Comment: I am using t-distribution for robustness but having nu free everywhere I think is too much freedom. I am trying something like ANOVA so I have some different groups which I want to fit with a t-distribution, but I want a common nu. Then I am also calculating some quantity from all the data together which should use the same nu.

Comment: I may not understand the problem, but why is not aggregating the data to calculate inference on nu not appropriate -- it appears this is what you want: a common nu? Is it because later inference on difference of groups may be effected (though data-leakage between groups via nu)?

Comment: Well its probably not so important - I just wanted to try it this way. It is actually the same data twice (once all grouped together, the other split into different classes). My model is that the class-conditional distributions should be t with common nu, and I am comparing it to the full data modelled with a single t. I want a common nu because that should be a property of the data set. Doing it all together is working OK, but I wanted to try with nu fit just to the class-seperated data (and then compare with nu fit only to the full data).

Comment: I guess my thinking was if there are large differences in means between the classes then single t model is not a correct match anymore and that could mess up the nu estimates I want for the best fitting class conditional models.

Comment: I'll add another edit to my answer, but what you want to do is very possible I believe.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you, what you are doing is out-of-sample testing. And to avoid data-leakage, you do not want to include the data `target_data` in the inference on `nu`.

A more appropriate way to handle this is to do the following:

```
nu = mc.Gamma('nu', 3, 2)
fit_obs = mc.NoncentralT('fit', fitmean, fitprec, nu, value=fit_data, observed=True)

N = target_data.shape[0]
predictive_obs = mc.NoncentralT('predictive', mean, prec, nu, size=N )
```

This way, you get a new variable `predictive_obs`, which is a distribution of *possible* realizations of the test data, given the training-data-fitted `nu` variable. (I made `predictive_obs` size `N` so it returns samples of equal size of the testing data set). From this, we can compare how likely we are, given the fitted `nu`, to see the target dataset.

For example, if your predictive samples, provided in `mcmc.trace("predictive")`, have very very fat tails, and your observed target data has thin tails, perhaps the fit is not correct. See [here](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/modelchecking.html#goodness-of-fit) for some examples of goodness-of-fit visualizations.

---

Using a deterministic wrapper, like your edit, still adds that data to the inference. I'll demonstrate:

Instead of an informative prior, like the Gamma you chose, I'm going to use a non-informative prior (a Uniform), just so there is no bias and the conclusion is clear:

Using the code:

```
nu = mc.Uniform( 'nu', 0,40)
fit_data = np.random.randn( 500 )
```

We should see the posterior of `nu` away from 0, as the data is from a Normal (which is a Student-T with a large `nu`.) This is without any "testing data" included. We see this posterior on `nu`:

[image]

We add heavy tailed data to be the `testing_data`,

```
target_data = np.array( [-10., -5., 6., 8.] ) #very unlikely values, would promote small nu
```

If we add your deterministic `fix_nu` variable, and `the target_data`

```
def fix_nu( nu = nu ):
   return nu

test_obs = mc.NoncentralT('test_obs', 0, 1, nu, value=target_data, observed=True)
```

and running the same as above, we get:

[image]

I should make it clear: this plot is the previous inference and the new inference. The large difference in the distributions implies the `testing_data` has been included in the inference.

---

I think what you want to do is possible. Even if the means (and prec) are very different, so long as the assumption (which should be tested) that $\nu$ are equal, something like the following is totally valid:

```
nu = mc.Gamma('nu', 3, 2)
fit_obsA = mc.NoncentralT('fitA', fitmeanA, fitprecA, nu, value=fit_dataA, observed=True)
fit_obsB = mc.NoncentralT('fitB', fitmeanB, fitprecB, nu, value=fit_dataB, observed=True)
```

will perform inference on `nu`, (again, stressing under the assumption the `nu` are the same in the two groups).

Comment: Thanks, I have seen it. It was reading that which prompted me to get started with pymc! I am not actually doing out-of-sample testing, it was part of my model that I wanted nu fit only to some data. I have also tried making a fixed_nu as a deterministic wrapper around nu and I think that is working.

Comment: Yes the last point is what I have and it is working. The point of the question though is that I would like to do a similar thing, using the value of nu (inferred jointly across the groups) for the combined data set - without the combined data set (which may be very spread out if there are large differences in means between the groups) affecting the value of nu. So I want to use the value to model data without that data affecting the likelihood of the nu value.

Comment: I want to do: fit_joint = mc.NoncentralT('fitjoint', jointmean, jointprec, nu, value=np.r_[fit_dataA, fit_dataB], observed=True) - But without affecting the value of nu ... since if the means are very different the joint data will be very spread out and this might pull the value of nu down to compensate.

Comment: I was wondering if I could keep nu as a parent of fit_joint, but manually remove fit_joint from the children of nu - but I don't know enough about the PyMC model structure to tell if this is possible

Comment: I've been thinking about this for quite some time. Unfortunately, I have no definite answer yet, so I'll have to think more.